# Selcting Specific Value From SQL Table Grouping Them

Tags: sql, .net, sql-query-store

`[{"OI":1012,"OK":"000010","Q":1,"SC":0,"TN":"Artists","TV":"Munna","UI":34}]`, This is a value of column named "oTags", I need to select only "TV" from these values in gourp by name, like "Munna". How can I do taht?

Comment: can I double check: you have a column `oTags` that contains text that is a JSON array of objects with multiple properties, and you're after a specific property value from the (first?) object in the array?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes you got my point.

Comment: note: this smells a bit "inner platform effect"; you may want to check that you aren't better off using tables and columns for this data

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have a text (`[n]varchar`) column (`oTags`) that contains a value that is a JSON array with one element that *has* a `TV` property, and you want to read that property, then:

```sql
select JSON_VALUE(yt.oTags, '$[0].TV') as [TV]
from yourtable yt
where ...
```

(or whatever else you want to do with the `JSON_VALUE` result)